# How to restore "invisible" mouse pointer in Mint 18.2 guest under VirtualBox?

Tags: windows-10, laptop, virtualbox, mouse, linux-mint

This problem seems to have multiple sources and multiple solutions, none of which have worked for me yet.

Scenario:
VirtualBox 5.1.28 running on Win 10 host on Asus Laptop with  GTX 770M graphics
Guest is Linux Mint 18.2.

I've removed the guest additions which came with the install, and added the Guest Additions from the VirtualBox Devices->Install Guest additions CD as part of the debugging, which hasn't changed the symptoms.

Initial install and boot up work fine, but Cinnamon is running in software rendering graphics mode, but I *can* see the mouse pointer.  The fix for software mode is to turn on 3d Acceleration in VirtualBox and reboot.  I do that, and the graphcis all look fine, no more software rendering mode, but after login, no visible mouse pointer.

The mouse pointer works, clicks items and selects, it just isn't visible.  I can turn off 3d acceleration, go back into software rendered mode, and the pointer comes back.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I believe there is an option inside VirtualBox itself where you can make the mousecursor invisible when hovering guests VM's so that you can see the Guest's mouse cursor, and it can be disabled. Not sure if this is a setting you set for the individual VM or for all VM's. Alternatively, look into the settings of Mint if you can change the mouse cursor there.

Comment: Thanks lpchip, but it's the guest mouse cursor I want. I'm fine if the host cursor goes invisible over the VMs, to let me see it. I'm just not seeing the guest cursor at all after login when Cinnamon starts.